# Workaround for indexing limitations of matfile command

Tags: matlab

I have a very large number of large data files. I would like to be able to categorize the data in each file, and then save the filename to a cell array, such that at the end I'll have one cell array of filenames for each category of data, which I could then save to a `mat` file so that I can then come back later and run analysis on each category. It might look something like this:

```
MatObj = matfile('listOfCategorizedFilenames.mat');
MatObj.boring = {};
MatObj.interesting = {};

files = dir(directory);
K = numel(files);

for k=1:K
    load(files(k).name,'data')
    metric = testfunction(data)

    if metric < threshold
        MatObj.boring{end+1} = files(k).name;
    else
        MatObj.interesting{end+1} = files(k).name;
    end
end
```

Because the list of files is very long, and `testfunction` can be slow, I'd like to set this to run unattended overnight or over the weekend (this is a stripped down version, `metric` might return one of several different categories), and in case of crashes or unforeseen errors, I'd like to save the data on the fly rather than populating a cell array in memory and dumping to disk at the end.

The problem is that using `matfile` will not allow cell indexing, so the save step throws an error. My question is, is there a workaround for this limitation? Is there better way to incrementally write the filenames to a list that would be easy to retrieve later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with `matfile`, so I cannot help you with that. As a quick and dirty solution, I would just write the filenames to two different text-files. Quick testing suggests that the data is flushed to disk straight away and that the text-files are OK even if you close matlab without doing a fclose (to simulate a crash). Untested code:

```
files = dir(directory);
K = numel(files);

boring = fopen('boring.txt', 'w');
interesting = fopen('interesting.txt', 'w');

for k=1:K
    load(files(k).name,'data')
    metric = testfunction(data)

    if metric < threshold
        fprintf(boring, '%s\n', files(k).name);
    else
        fprintf(interesting, '%s\n', files(k).name);
    end
end

%be nice and close files
fclose(boring);
fclose(interesting);
```

Processing the boring/interesting text files afterwards should be trivial. If you would also write the directory listing to a separate file before starting the loop, it should be pretty easy (either by hand or automatically) to figure out where to continue in case of a crash.

Comment: This worked. When I did get an unforeseen error that crashed the script, I was able to just load in the `boring` and `interesting` file lists, skip the file if it was already processed, and append to the end if it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Mat files are probably the most efficient way to store lists of files, but I guess whenever I've had this problem, I make a cell array and save it using `xlswrite` or `fprintf` into a document that I can just reload later.

You said the save step throws an error, so I assume this part is okay, right?

```
for k=1:K
    load(files(k).name,'data')
    metric = testfunction(data)

    if metric < threshold
        MatObj.boring{end+1} = files(k).name;
    else
        MatObj.interesting{end+1} = files(k).name;
    end
end
```

Personally, I just then write,

```
xlswrite('name.xls', MatObj.interesting, 1, 'A1');
[~, ~, list] = xlsread('name.xls'); % later on
```

Or if you prefer text,

```
% I'm assuming here that it's just a single list of text strings.
fid = fopen('name.txt', 'w');
for row=1:nrows
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', MatObj.interesting{row});
end
fclose(fid);
```

And then later open with `fscanf`. I just use the `xlswrite`. I've never had a problem with it, and it's not noticeably slow enough to detract me from using it. I know my answer is just a workaround instead of a real solution, but I hope it helps.

Comment: The lines that throw the error are the ones that look like `MatObj.boring{end+1} = files(k).name;`. MATLAB doesn't like the cell indexing. I've always found the `xlswrite` and `xlsread` functions to be incredibly slow, but it's been many years and many MATLAB versions since I've used them, so I'll give them another benchmark. I suppose I could use a different tab for each list.

Comment: This worked, but ended up being a little slower than saving to an ascii file, and I always try to avoid saving to closed source Microsoft file formats if I can help it.

Comment: True. I agree it's not the best/fastest. But LibreOffice Calc opens and saves them just fine, and I found out the hard way that if you let your Microsoft Office license expire, the MATLAB read and write functions still work.